# Does multiplayer difficulty scale with the number of players?

Tags: mass-effect-3-multiplayer, mass-effect-3

In other words, will the enemies in a two player match on bronze difficulty do more damage and have more health than the enemies in a four player match of the same difficulty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging from my experiences with the demo, no.

You face the same number of enemies whether you have one or three people with you -- and going in undermanned can be very spectacularly fatal.

Comment: This matches my experience also.

Comment: +1 - Every time I try to start a game without waiting for *at least* two more people to join, I find myself in a whole new world of hurt.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my experience yes.

If you go in with less than 4 players or 4 players of lower rank then there are the same number of lower enemies but you get fewer top enemies such as Titans, Phantoms, etc.